# Getting XML atttributes that are deep in the structure using .net core

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core, xml-parsing

I have an xml structure similar to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--The structure-->
<myXMLRoot>
    <tree>
        <category title="Title A">Hi</category>
    </tree>
    <tree>
        <category title="Title B">Text</category>
    </tree>
</myXMLRoot>
```

If I know the structure like above, what is a quick way to get the category title for both tree sections?

I want to avoid parsing the entire file.

So perhaps something that does this:

```
var first = getXMLTitle("myXMLRoot/tree(0)/category[title]");
var second = getXMLTitle("myXMLRoot/tree(1)/category[title]");
```

I want something that deep links into the XML using .NET core.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for this XPath. Please take a look on code bellow

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(@"C:\somepath-to-xml\some-xml.xml");
var navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
var iterator = navigator.Select("myXMLRoot/tree/category/@title");
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current.Value);
}
```

This code iterate over all title. Small note in your example you have small mistake `cateogyr` but should be `category`